# Save memory overhead with DictReader

Tags: python

I use [`csv.DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to read data from a CSV file. When the reader is iterated over, it yields dictionaries with keys taken from the CSV header and the values per row:

```
with open(filename) as h:
    data = csv.DictReader(h)
    for row in data:
        # row is dict
```

Each row is a dictionary with [keys](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), and each row has *exactly the same keys*. In case when the values are integers and the keys (strings) are long, the keys occupy more memory space than the values..

Can I iterate the rows in the way that the keys of each row point to the same *instance* of keys, so I save memory space per row?

Note that I don't know the keys in advance - they are taken from CSV header. Otherwise I could use [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or [`__slots__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/python-slots)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use a `namedtuple`; build it from the first row yourself:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as h:
    data = csv.reader(h)
    headers = next(data)
    RowTuple = namedtuple('RowTuple', headers)
    for row in data:
        row = RowTuple(row)
```

This is essentially what `DictReader()` does; take the keys from the first row.

Note that the `DictReader()` code creates the dictionary with `dict(zip(self.fieldnames, row))`; this *reuses* the same strings for each row, and the only memory overhead you have is the `dict` table itself plus the hash values for the keys (these are recalculated each time and cached). The strings for the keys are not created anew for each row. The `namedtuple` approach doesn't either, but doesn't need to keep hashes since `__slots__` are used.